# Android DropBox SDK can't upload file, or only 18 bytes of it

Tags: java, android, dropbox

So I want to upload a file from the app's internal storage to DropBox witch I can't get working

i goth the file location in the variable location from and i know if works because I'm already using this path for making a copy off the file to the sdcard

```
         String currentDBPath = "\\simon.vestergaard.note.calender\\databases\\NoteCalender";
         String backupDBPath = "NoteCalender";


         File locationfrom = new File(data + ""+data+"/simon.vestergaard.note.calender"+ "/databases",backupDBPath);enter code here
```

i need to use the dropbox to upload the file where I'm using this metode 
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.2.2-docs/index.html
but it requires the file as a input stream how can i due this?

my question is how can i get to the file thats stored in data\data\simon.vestergaard.note.calender\databases\NoteCalender and get it as a inputstream and send i with putfileOverWrite ore put file ??

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is not how you get the contents of a stream. This post might be helpful to you: [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: okay ty i changed somem off the code and look at it a little more and i found out that im giving the bytearrayinputstream im giving it a vaibal not a file with is what i wan't to

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't even notice that. You're using getBytes() on a string which is not going to get you the contents of the file.

Comment: due you know how i cut get the contents off the file / all bytes the file contain??